# How to mount two seperate applications inside one Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am creating a `frontend` and a `backend` application inside one `Vue 3` project. Everything works fine except that `app.js` is throwing following error, depending on which component is visited in the browser.

I you visit the `app.vue`:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#cms" returned null.
```

and if you visit the `cms.vue`:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#app" returned null.
```

The mounting file **`app.js`** looks like this:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from "../vue/app";
import cms from "../vue/cms";
import router from "./router";

createApp(app)
    .use(router)
    .mount("#app");

createApp(cms)
    .use(router)
    .mount("#cms");
```

Is there any way I can prevent the browser warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could query the document for those elements, and only mount the ones that exist:

```js
const appEl = document.querySelector('#app');
if (appEl) {
  createApp(app).use(router).mount(appEl);
}

const cmsEl = document.querySelector('#cms');
if (cmsEl) {
  createApp(cms).use(router).mount(cmsEl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change

this

import {createApp} from **'vue';**

for

import {createApp} from '**vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler**';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).